# Show that $\tan(\alpha)= \frac{Q\sin(\theta)}{P+Q\cos(\theta)}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

Please help.

$$\tan(\alpha)= \frac{Q\sin(\theta)}{P+Q\cos(\theta)}$$

[image: THIS IS THE PICTURE]

the equation in the diagram is a bit wrong , instead of P+cos(ϴ), it will be P+Qcos(ϴ)

Comment: https://www.mathstopia.net/vectors/parallelogram-law-vector-addition

Comment: Hints only in my answer. You have to try. Post with specific problems you have following those hints.

Comment: By the way, what you're required to prove should be $\displaystyle \tan \alpha = \frac{Q\sin\theta}{P + Q\cos\theta}$. Note the extra $Q$ in the denominator that's missing from your expression. Maybe that's why you're finding it impossible.

Comment: Ohh, thanks a lot. Yes, I just realised I missed out the "Q" in the diagram, but in my copy "Q" was present, I just forgot to add that here ( I'm using this site for the first time ). Thank you so much, I'll recommend this site to my friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints only.

Label the vertices of the parallelogram clockwise starting with bottom left as $A, B, C, D$. From the top right vertex drop an altitude of the parallelogram to its base. Let this altitude end at point $E$. Consider the small right triangle $\triangle CDE$. What is its height? What is its base?

Now consider the large right triangle $\triangle ACE$. What is its height? What is its base? Therefore what is $\tan \alpha$?

Answer (score 0):

By low of sines  we obtain
$$\frac{P}{\sin(\theta-\alpha)}=\frac{Q}{\sin\alpha}$$ or
$$P\sin\alpha=Q\sin\theta\cos\alpha-Q\cos\theta\sin\alpha$$ or
$$(P+Q\cos\theta)\sin\alpha=Q\sin\theta\cos\alpha$$ and if $\alpha\neq90^{\circ}$
$$\tan\alpha=\frac{Q\sin\theta}{P+Q\cos\theta}$$ and we are done!

Comment: Wow, this is even simpler than the previous method!
neatly done using the sine rule
thank you

Comment: @Alavi Steam You are welcome!